# Launching application in favorites creates 2nd icon on taskbar

Tags: gnome, .desktop

I have [Element-Nightly](https://element.io/get-started#nightly) installed using the official installation instructions.

This creates a desktop file in `/usr/share/applications`, which I've added to my GNOME taskbar:

```
seth@seth-pc-tux:/usr/share/applications$ cat element-desktop-nightly.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Element-Nightly
Exec=/opt/Element-Nightly/element-desktop-nightly %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=element-desktop-nightly
StartupWMClass=element
Comment=A feature-rich client for Matrix.org
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/element;
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;Chat;
```

However, when I launch the application, it creates a new icon in the task bar instead of putting the window against my favorites.

Both are named Element-Nightly, and if I click the icon from my favorites, it focuses the window which is represented by the 2nd icon.

[image: Element-Nightly in my favorites, with another Element-Nightly icon after.]

The stable version of Element behaves as expected. Any idea why it's doing this, and how to make the window open against the icon from my favorites instead of a new one?

Answer (score 1):

The cause was that the Desktop Entry was called

`element-desktop-nightly.desktop`

Renaming it to

`element-nightly.desktop`

resolves the issue and allows them to group correctly.

An issue was created on the GitHub repository which notes the solution:
https://github.com/vector-im/element-web/issues/13780

More info on file naming for Desktop Entry files:
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1):

You should align the desktop filename with `WM_CLASS` got from `xprop`. That will combine your running app window with anchored icon.